# MailApp not sending with large number of recipients

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, email, quota

My code takes an input of emails that looks like this:

> email1@gmail.com, email2@gmail.com, email3@gmail.com ...

and tries to send them an email using the following code.

```js
function sendEmail(form) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var body = form.body;
  var bcc = form.bccfield;
  var cc = form.ccfield;
  var to = form.tofield;
  var subject = form.subject;
   var eHandle = ss.getSheetByName("Email Handling");
  var sig = eHandle.getRange(10, 2).getValue();
  var img = eHandle.getRange(11, 2).getValue();    
  var sigImage = '<img src ="' + img + '" >';
  
MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: to,
  cc: cc,
  bcc: bcc,
    subject: subject,
   
  htmlBody: body.replace(/\n/g, '<br>') + sig + sigImage});
  }
```

It seemed to always be working but now I'm trying to send to a class list of parents (about 55 at a time) and it just doesn't send anything (the code doesn't even finish). I am GSuite for Education so I should have a limit of over 1,000 recipients per day.

I'm pretty sure the only difference which now causes a problem is the number of recipients.

Comment: what does `.getRemainingQuota()` say?

Comment: @TheMaster Good question. Just checked: 1381

Comment: @Marios Thanks, that's great! Now I'm working on the script to split and send seperate emails. Probably going to have to post a question for that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You are not allowed to sent an email to more than 50 recipients at a time.

Number of recipients per email is part of [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

You are only allowed to sent an email with a maximum number of **50** recipients.

[image: example]

An obvious workaround would be to split the recipients into two or more (depending upon the number of recipients) different emails so this hard limitation won't be violated.