# MailApp BCC message details not showing in sent folder

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, gmail

When I send a bcc'd email using MailApp it sends, is recieved, and the email shows up in the sender's sent folder. However, the email in the sent folder does not show the sender who they bcc'd like it normally would. It shows as an email that was sent TO the SENDER (even though the sender did not send it to themself).

Also, it appears that it is sending the email almost like a mailmerge. It ends up in the bcc recipients inbox showing them as the only recipient (not as a bcc recipient).

This is a real concern because you can't verify that you sent your email to 20+ people.

This was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60320477/mailapp-sendemail-bcc-not-shown-in-sent-items) with no answers.

```js
function sendEmail(form) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var body = form.body;
  var bcc = form.bccfield;
  var cc = form.ccfield;
  var to = form.tofield;
  var subject = form.subject;
   var eHandle = ss.getSheetByName("Email Handling");
  var sig = eHandle.getRange(10, 2).getValue();
  var img = eHandle.getRange(11, 2).getValue();    
  var sigImage = '<img src ="' + img + '" >';
  
MailApp.sendEmail(to, {
    to: to,
  cc: cc,
  bcc: bcc,
    subject: subject,
   
  htmlBody: body.replace(/\n/g, '<br>') + sig + sigImage});
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GmailApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app), it has an analogous [`sendEmail`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) method that does exactly what you want. You are also correct about the behavior of the `MailApp`'s method - the emails are sent as if they were separate emails<sup>0</sup>.

To see the difference first-hand, run the following snippet:

```
function testBcc() {

    const email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();

    const emailConfig = {
        to: email,
        bcc: email,
        htmlBody: `<p>Test message</p>`,
        subject: "test subject"
    };

    MailApp.sendEmail(emailConfig);
    GmailApp.sendEmail(
        emailConfig.to, emailConfig.subject,
        "",
        { htmlBody: emailConfig.htmlBody, bcc : emailConfig.bcc });
}
```

Note that you will need the following scopes:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email to `getEmail`
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail to `sendEmail` via `MailApp`
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send to `sendEmail` via `GmailApp`

---

<sup>0</sup> please note that your method signature is indeed incorrect as [Rubén](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64201859/11407695)'s answer mentions.

Comment: That's super helplful. I found out through another question  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64176235/mailapp-not-sending-with-large-number-of-recipients/64179014#64179014) that I am limited to Bccing 50 recipients. Is the same true of using the GmailApp? A user here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45938944/is-the-gmailapp-api-send-limit-the-same-as-mailapp) suggested no but it doesn't seem resolved and I'm not sure how to test it as I can't just email 50+ people for no reason.

Comment: @Luke - pretty much, `GmailApp` follows 2 quotas, don't bother checking ( if you only have a Gmail account, this testing will cost you half the daily quota ): [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), and [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why they are contradictory? The second one says 100 while the former says 50. Since the second specifies GmailApp I was hopeful.

Comment: @Luke - the general rule of thumb is that quotas from the "service quotas" apply, but you still can't do more than what is allowed in "sending limits", even if quotas do not specify the restriction. So, applied to your case, the 50 recipients limit takes precedence. You can use Gmail API directly to get the most out of the limitations, it is not that difficult to set up

Answer (score 3):

The Oleg's answer is correct, `MailApp.sendEmail(...)` doesn't work as you expect. Anyway, it's worthy to mention a problem  that according to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app there are four `sendEmail` methods for MailApp:

- `sendEmail(message)`
- `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)`
- `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)`
- `sendEmail(to, replyTo, subject, body)`

but your code is not using none mof them.

Replace

```
MailApp.sendEmail(to, {
    to: to,
  cc: cc,
  bcc: bcc,
    subject: subject,
   
  htmlBody: body.replace(/\n/g, '<br>') + sig + sigImage});
```

by

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: to,
  cc: cc,
  bcc: bcc,
  subject: subject, 
  htmlBody: body.replace(/\n/g, '<br>') + sig + sigImage
});
```